# Understanding some statement in proof of the Lagrange's Theorem ( Rosen's Elementary number theory, Theorem 12.21 )

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am reading the Rosen's Elementary number theory (sixth edition), proof of theorem 12.21 and stuck at understanding some statement.

> **Theorem 12.21. *Lagrange's Theorem.***. The infinite simple continued fraction of an irrational number is periodic if and only if this number is quadratic irrational.

I am reading the 'if' part ( his book p.510 ). He argued as follows :

Let $\alpha$ be a quadratic irrational, so that by Lemma 12.5, we can write $\alpha$ as

$$\alpha = (P_0 +\sqrt{d})/Q_0 ,$$

where $P_0 , Q_0, d$ are integers, $Q_0 \neq 0$, $d>0$, $d$ is not a perfect square, and $Q | (d-P_0^2)$.

Furthermore, by Theorem 12.22, we have $\alpha = [a_0 ; a_1, a_2 , \ldots]$, where

$$ \alpha_k=(P_k+ \sqrt{d})/Q_k,$$
$$ a_k = [ \alpha_k],$$
$$ P_{k+1} = a_kQ_k - P_k,$$
$$ Q_{k+1} = ( d- P_{k+1}^2 ) /Q_k, $$

for $k=0,1,2, \dots$

And through some argument ( If needed, I will upload more detailed argument ), the author shows that there is an integer $N$ such that $0 \le Q_k \le d $ and $ -\sqrt{d} < P_{k+1} < \sqrt{d}$ for $k \ge N$.

And he wrote that **" we see that there are only a finte number of possible values for the pair of integers $P_k, Q_k$ for $k>N$."** I don't understand why this statement is true until now. Isn't there a possibility that the sequence $(Q_k)$ and $(P_{k})$ could be bounded? Perhaps, if the subset $\{P_k\}$ ( or $\{Q_k\}$ ) of 'integers' is infinite set, then is it unbounded? Having written it, I think that this is a soft question but I propose this question to make this certainly sure :) Can anyone helps?

Comment: It is true that any bounded set of integers is finite (equivalently, any infinite set of integers is unbounded). Do you see why this is true? Does that resolve your question?

Comment: Thanks. Can we try to imitate https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Subset_of_Naturals_is_Finite_iff_Bounded ? :)  ( using that subset of finite set is finite ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand the question, but here is what I think is an answer (I'm posting this as an answer because it's a bit too long for a comment): the sequence $(Q_k)$ and $(P_k)$  are bounded, as the author has shown, but they are also integers, by definition. Therefore, they can only take finitely many values, because there are only finitely many integers between any two numbers. In this case, $Q_k$ (for sufficiently large $k$) can only be one of the finitely many $0, 1, 2, 3,..., d,$ and $P_k$ (for sufficiently large $k$), can only be one of the finitely many $a, a+1, a+2,...,0, 1, 2,..., b-2, b-1, b,$ where $a$ is the least integer greater than $-\sqrt{d}$, and $b$ is the least integer less than $\sqrt{d}.$

Comment: Thanks for kind and detailed answer. And..I think that there is a small errata : $a, a+1 , a+2 , \dots, 0 , \cdots $ is more correct? (  $a < a+1 < a+2 < \cdots $ )

Comment: I'm glad my answer helped, and you're certainly right! I've fixed it now.

Comment: Thank you!!~~~~